# Why does AS3 navigateToURL() only run once?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, browser, air

I'm calling **navigateToURL** on a click in my html embedded program (originally written for AIR mobile) to open an external page.

When run in debug mode locally (not in a browser), it works fine. I can click the icon 5 times and it'll open up 5 browser instances to the URL.

But when I run it from the browser, it'll open the URL only **once**. If I click the icon 5 times, it'll open the URL on the **first time** and not after that.

I tried calling **javascript:console.log('test')** on click and that runs only once, too. So it seems that the navigateToURL isn't coming out of the swf after the first call.

I've set allowscriptaccess to always and that didn't change the behaviour.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using navigateToURL(YOUR_REQUEST, "_blank"); That way it will open the request in a new window. Maybe it simply loads the same page over and over making it only "refresh".

Comment: Remove javascript from the tag list.

Comment: Thanks guys. it turns out the problem was a crossdomain.xml problem. Once that was cleared up (www.domain vs. no-www.domain) it ran fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed this was with a `crossdomain.xml` file.

The problem was that depending on if the user typed `www.domain.com` or just `domain.com`, it saw the two as two different sites and was looking for `crossdomain.xml`.

I could have fixed this by making all my links relative (or at least starting from root like this: `/images/books/Chicken.jpg`).

I instead decided to create the `crossdomain.xml` file which fixed everything.